# Is it possible "which" refers to "a verb" or "adverb"?

Tags: grammar

> 1. Cheetahs can run fast, which they can't move in water.
> 2. Lions can live in the savanna, which they can't in the jungle.

In number 1, which is referring to "fast".

In number 2, which is referring to "live".

Can it be grammatically acceptable that "which" can refer to a verb or adverb like that?

Up until now, I've only learnt "which" can refer to the part of its preceding sentence, noun, or adjective.

I'm just asking whether it's acceptable regardless of the awkwardness of my sentences.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93376/discussion-on-question-by-floret-is-it-possible-which-refers-to-a-verb-or-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Which can refer back to a verb. Some examples:

> Cheetahs can run fast on land, which they can't do in water.

Which refers back to "run fast" (verb + adverb)

(A comment suggests that which here refers back to all of "Cheetahs can run fast". I disagree. Another comment says this is ungrammatical. I don't see anything ungrammatical or akward about this sentence.)

> He was able to make money on the stock market, which not everyone can accomplish.

"Which" refers back to "make money", sentence sounds perfectly natural to me. No "do" required.

> He finished college in 2 years, which is harder than you might think.

"Which" refers back to "finish college in 2 years" (verbal phrase)

> He moves gracefully, which is essential for a dancer.

"Which" refers back to "moves gracefully" (verb + adverb).

> The rock fell slowly, which is only natural on the Moon.

"Which" refers back to "fell slowly" (verb + adverb).

Comment: @Man_From_India  I disagree, and have so indicated in the answer. Why do you think "Cheetahs can run fast on land, which they can't do in water. " is not grammatical?

Comment: @ Man_From_India In all my sentences above, "which" refers back to a verb+adverb combination, or to a verb phrase. Which can also refer back to a verb without an adverb. I can't think oif a sentance where "which" refers back to an adverb but not the verb. It is possible for which to refer back to a noun or noun phrase. It may be even more common. Example "Like a man in irons, which isn't glad to go" (Kipling, "The 'eathen" ) strictly that should have been 'who", verse often bends rules for effect.

Answer (score 1):

As David Siegel says in his answer, "which" can refer back to a verb alone, or to a verb+adverb combo, and he gives examples of it which sound grammatical and reasonable.

As far as "which" referring back only to an adverb (not the verb, but just the adverb), it seems to be difficult to come up with examples.

But I submit these three:

> We flew nonstop, which we wouldn't have been able to fly back when I was a child.
>
> He danced very gracefully, which he wouldn't even have been able to
>   walk, had he been chewing gum.
>
> She salted the soup insufficiently, which she also chilled the wine.

Here the "which" stands in for "nonstop", "gracefuly", and "insufficiently", in that order.

OK, all 3 of those sentences sound ridiculous in my opinion. Unless someone can come up with one that sounds a little more idiomatic, I think that the answer regarding adverbs is, no, "which" can't substitute for them.

Comment: However: "The best way to enjoy a fine wine is slowly, which also happens to be the best way to tour the Wine Country." "The Rabbi says we should pray mindfully, which is how certain Buddhists recommend we do everything."

Comment: But I have no idea how come "which" as in **"This was the long way, which we had to go"** can stand in for "the long way". As you can see, "the long ways" is a noun phrase as a complement for "this" as well as an adverbial phrase as modifying "go". Is it just an exception?